# Anime about a girl that is saved from a strange life form in a forest by a man

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched an anime once about a girl with brown hair. She met a man in a forest that saved her from a strange life form. That man ends up being her soulmate from another time line. I believe they was reincarnations of gods? I think the man was tall with black hair? I also believe he had powers that relate to destruction or fire?

Comment: Please edit your question and try to answer the questions [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/21351)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Origin Spirit of the past ?
[image: Origin spirit of the past pic]

The story (from what I remember) is a girl waking up from hypersleep,  she lived in our near future. She awakes in a far away future, where apocalypse came and nature took its rights back. She meets a boy that becomes her soulmate, and is capable of fusing with a nature spirit to save her.
(I saw it a long time ago, sorry if it's not that exactly)

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked for a anime movie called Mononoke? It is also about reincarnated gods in a forest. Even if it is not what you are looking for, it is a recommendation of mine. One of the best anime movies i've ever seen.

Comment: At the moment this is a recommendation rather than an answer to the question. Could you [edit] to reword it as an answer and explain how it matches the OPs description?

Comment: By Mononoke did you mean [*Princess Mononoke*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Mononoke)?

Comment: Yes , *Princes Mononoke , i'm sorry.

Comment: I've seen *Princess Mononoke* and I don't believe it matches. Prince Ashitaka has powers relating to his curse but they're not destruction or fire-related, and while there are gods, I don't recall there being any indication that Mononoke and Ashitaka themselves are reincarnations of gods.